# convert ID3D11Resource* to Bitmap or CDC for MFC code

Tags: bitmap, mfc, directx

In a MFC project, I need to save a `D3D11Resource*` to a `CDC`, `CBitmap`, or `BITMAP`, not as a file.

First I'm validating that I can save off the Texture as bitmap object or memory-mapped file, before using the bitmap. Not going for speed here; just need the bitmap.

Using `DirectXTex`, I've gotten as far as:

```
DirectX::ScratchImage preImage;
hr = DirectX::CaptureTexture(dev11.Get(), devcon11.Get(), (ID3D11Resource*)texture, preImage);
```

But it is seeming like it is a bit more complicated, since using a default device and context ends up with a `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_TYPELESS`, which can't be converted (using `DirectX::Convert(...)`).

So, I thought I should venture into drawing to `ID2D1DCRenderTarget` from the `ID3D11Resource*` but haven't figured out how to do that yet, either.

I sure did expect this to be much simpler.

Anybody have an easy way to get from `ID3D11Resource*` to `CDC` or `CBitmap`?

**=================================================================**

Adding code here, to be clear, since I have no window to draw to, and do not OWN the original ID3D11Resource* ... so I've concocted this scratch code to test before I make it "robust":

```
bool PopulateMemDC(void* texture)
{
    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> dev11;
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> devcon11;
    // Create the device and device context objects
    HRESULT hr;
    ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> local;
    ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> texture2D;
    local.Attach((ID3D11Resource*)texture);
    local->GetDevice(&dev11);
    dev11->GetImmediateContext(&devcon11);
    DirectX::ScratchImage preImage;
    hr = DirectX::CaptureTexture(dev11.Get(), devcon11.Get(), (ID3D11Resource*)texture, preImage);
    const DirectX::TexMetadata metadata = preImage.GetMetadata();
    if (metadata.dimension == DirectX::TEX_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D)
    {
        ComPtr<IDXGISurface1> surface;
        hr = local.Get()->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGISurface1), (void**)&surface);
        HDC hdc;
        surface->GetDC(FALSE, &hdc);
        CDC* cdc = CDC::FromHandle(hdc);
        cdc->CreateCompatibleDC(&copyDc);
        cdc->GetBoundsRect(&bounds, 0);
        copyDc.BitBlt(0, 0, bounds.right - bounds.left, bounds.bottom - bounds.top, cdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        cdc->DeleteDC();
        //CBitmap* pmap = cdc->GetCurrentBitmap();
        //if (pmap != NULL)
        //{
        //  BITMAP bmp;
        //  pmap->GetBitmap(&bmp);
        //  BYTE* bmpBuffer = (BYTE*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, bmp.bmWidthBytes * bmp.bmHeight);
        //  DWORD dwValue = pmap->GetBitmapBits(bmp.bmWidthBytes * bmp.bmHeight, bmpBuffer);
        //  DWORD dwValue2 = bmap.SetBitmapBits(bmp.bmWidthBytes * bmp.bmHeight, bmpBuffer);
        //  GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)bmpBuffer);//Free memory
        //}
        //else
        //  hr = (HRESULT)(-1);
        //
    }

    local.Detach();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }
    //hr = DirectX::Convert(preImage.GetImages(), preImage.GetImageCount(), preImage.GetMetadata(), DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0, 1.0f, image);
    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}
```

But this fails to populate the HDC at `surface->GetDC(FALSE, &hdc);`

1. How do I access the data from the original resource for the BitBlt to a new DC? Can I just use the devcon11 as the source?
2. How do I get a new DC to save/BitBlt the contents to?

Comment: You can draw on window, create memory dc and memory bitmap, then bitblt the content

Comment: Where do I BitBlt the content from? What is the source? Is it the devcon11?

Comment: @user1953804 
[https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/CaptureTexture](CaptureTexture)
Looking back at this problem, the `texture` was the source.  I was taking in the ID3D11Resource and extracting the "images" (there was only 1) into the ScratchImage preImage, then converting that to the CBitmap using the preImage.GetImage
So, in this case, I wasn't bitBlt'ing anything; just extracting the image from the resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that worked, for now, but I'm still looking for a way that does not make assumptions about the incoming data.

Also, this is dangerous (not safe) code:

```
static
DirectX::ScratchImage preImage;

bool PopulateMemDC(void* texture)
{
    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> dev11;
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> devcon11;
    // Create the device and device context objects
    HRESULT hr;
    ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> local;
    ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> texture2D;
    local.Attach((ID3D11Resource*)texture);
    local->GetDevice(&dev11);
    dev11->GetImmediateContext(&devcon11);
    DirectX::ScratchImage localImage;
    hr = DirectX::CaptureTexture(dev11.Get(), devcon11.Get(), (ID3D11Resource*)texture, localImage);
    if (localImage.GetMetadata().format == DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_TYPELESS)
        localImage.OverrideFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);
    DirectX::FlipRotate(localImage.GetImages(), localImage.GetImageCount(), localImage.GetMetadata(), DirectX::TEX_FR_FLIP_VERTICAL, preImage);
    local.Detach();
    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}

void RenderR8G8B8A8TYPELESS(CBitmap& bitmap)
{
    BITMAP bmp;
    bitmap.GetBitmap(&bmp);
    SIZE_T bmpSize = bmp.bmWidthBytes * bmp.bmHeight;
    SIZE_T pixSize = preImage.GetPixelsSize();
    BYTE* bmpBuffer = (BYTE*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, bmpSize);
    const DirectX::TexMetadata metadata = preImage.GetMetadata();
    if (metadata.dimension == DirectX::TEX_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D)
    {
        const DirectX::Image* img = preImage.GetImage(0, 0, 0);
        const uint8_t *pSrc = img->pixels;
        memcpy_s(bmpBuffer, bmpSize, pSrc, pixSize);
    }
    bitmap.SetBitmapBits(bmpSize, bmpBuffer);
    GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)bmpBuffer);//Free memory

}
```